# Which Stack Exchange is the best for questions on Microsoft Store?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am looking to ask a question pertaining to reverting to an older version of a certain application I have downloaded off the Microsoft Store.

Is there any specific site which accepts such questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it's a native Windows feature, it qualifies as 'computer software'. Such a question belongs to [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about ...
>
> - computer hardware,
> - computer software, or
> - personal and home computer networking
>
> ...
>
> ... then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

There are already a few questions about the [Microsoft Store](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-store), but it's not a very popular topic.